# Who are the persons on this My Policeman cover?

Tags: e-m-forster, my-policeman, bethan-roberts

I was searching for the 2012 novel written by Bethan Roberts and I looked at the cover:

[image: My Policeman]

I got curious to know who are the persons on this cover. Because one of them is looking at the camera and his face is totally obvious.

So I searched if the novel is based on a true story. I found [this](https://amp.theguardian.com/books/2012/feb/17/e-m-forster-my-policeman) Guardian article written by Bethan Roberts herself.

> For 40 years, EM Forster and the policeman Bob Buckingham were in a loving relationship. Buckingham was 28, Forster 51, when the two met.

Now that E. M. Forster -who was a famous author himself- doesn't look like the person on the cover (as the Guardian article states he was 51 when he met Buckingham, actually) I tried to find a picture of the real Robert Buckingham and I found [this](https://expo63.tumblr.com/post/91769369572/e-m-forster-and-his-wondrous-muddle-for). But this one also doesn't look like the person on the cover.

[image: Buckingham]

So who are the persons on the cover? Are they famous persons? Are they regular people? If yes does the publisher have the consent of the person on the cover to spread his picture? Also, where is the city the photo has been taken?

Comment: There's a higher resolution image of the cover available here - right click to get a context menu to download it https://sevenoaksbookshop.co.uk/shop/my-policeman-soon-to-be-a-film-starring-harry-styles-and-emma-corrin-by-bethan-roberts/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As someone who has spent many months attending language schools in Brighton, I can say with some authority that the image is of Brighton Pier. This is reasonable, as this is the town where the novel is set.

Doing a reverse image search on the cover reveals that it is a stock image whose copyright is held by Top Foto, entitled "[Brighton - enjoying paddling and swimming in the sea near the pier](https://www.mediastorehouse.com/topfoto/sussex-life/brighton-enjoying-paddling-swimming-sea-near-11263618.html)". Comparing the original with the cover reveals that the photo has been colorized, cropped, and slightly edited to remove two additional figures:

[image: Black and white image of people swimming near Brighton Pier]

So the people on the cover are almost certainly ordinary members of the public, and presumably the publisher paid the photo agency for permission to use the image.

Matt Thrower noted in comments that another change was made to the original photo, namely that the third man from the left has had his face photoshopped. In the original, he was wearing a bathing cap and was looking obliquely toward the camera, but on the cover-version his hair is exposed and he looks directly into the camera. As he is the only figure in the original photograph whose face was visible, rendering him at least notionally identifiable, I can hypothesise that the graphic designer altered the image to avoid any legal problems concerning the original man needing to give consent for his image to be used. Certainly the face does not seem to be anyone particularly notable, and as the OP noted, it does not resemble Forster or Buckingham. Willing to be proven wrong though!

Comment: This is a nice bit of detective work, but I think it actually deepens the mystery regarding the figure looking at the camera. While the two figures with their back to the camera look the same, the other figure in the original photo looks to be wearing a bathing cap, which the figure on the cover is not. So the publishers have specifically edited -that figure- to give it a different face for reasons unknown.

Comment: Well, the location and two of the figures are identified, so I think the mystery is unravelling, rather than deepening  ;)  Strange to photoshop the third figure like that though.